# How to share a document library item with Distribution/Security Groups?

Tags: permissions, groups, audience-targeting, item-level-permissions, distribution-lists

I got a document library. There are many documents.And I got security groups. But i cannot find them for manage permission. I want to give them permissons to see the file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **Distribution Group** and **Security Group** among **SharePoint Groups** those are **AD Groups**.

For your requirement you need create new groups and assign them the permission you need.

Please check this [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Understanding-SharePoint-groups-94d9b261-161e-4ace-829e-eca1c8cd2eb8) for more details about SharePoint Groups.